# bestglm alternatives for dataset with many variables

Tags: r

R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
RStudio 0.96.316
Win XP, last update

I do have a dataset with 40 variables and 15.000 observations. I would like to use bestglm  to search for possible good models (logistic regression). I've tried bestglm, however it doesn't work for such medium sized dataset. After several trials, I think bestglm fails when there is more then approx 30 variables, at least on my computer (4G ram, dual core).

You can try bestglm limits on your own:

```
library(bestglm)

bestBIC_test <- function(number_of_vars) {

# Simulate data frame for logistic regression
glm_sample <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*number_of_vars), 100))

# Get some 1/0 variable
glm_sample[,number_of_vars][glm_sample[,number_of_vars] > mean(glm_sample[,number_of_vars]) ] <- 1
glm_sample[,number_of_vars][glm_sample[,number_of_vars] != 1 ] <- 0

# Try to calculate best model
bestBIC  <- bestglm(glm_sample, IC="BIC", family=binomial)

}

# Test bestglm with increasing number of variables
bestBIC_test(10) # OK, running
bestBIC_test(20) # OK, running
bestBIC_test(25) # OK, running
bestBIC_test(28) # Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1024.0 Mb
bestBIC_test(30) # Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Gb
bestBIC_test(40) # Error in rep(-Inf, 2^p) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Are there any alternatives I can use in R to search for possible good models?

Comment: Your first stop for this kind of question really shouldn't be SO, but the [Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) at CRAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, for starters an exhaustive search for the best subset of 40 variables requires creating 2^40 models which is over a trillion.  That is likely your issue.

Exhaustive best subsets search is generally not considered optimal for over 20 or so variables.

A better bet is something like forward stepwise selection which is around (40^2+40)/2 models so around 800.

Or even BETTER (best in my opinion) regularized logistic regression using the lasso via the `glmnet` package.

Good overview [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxXnVFYbQ9rnK4WgHVVgY5PFwTI4NCYq1).

Comment: also consider the [glmulti package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

You could try exploring the package [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html), which also has tools for model selection. I was able to fit a model with 15000 observations without issue:

```
number_of_vars <- 40

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(15000*number_of_vars), 15000))
dat[,number_of_vars][dat[,number_of_vars] > mean(dat[,number_of_vars]) ] <- 1
dat[,number_of_vars][dat[,number_of_vars] != 1 ] <- 0

library(caret)
result <- train(dat[,1:39], dat[,40], family = "binomial", method = "glm")
result$finalModel
```

I would consult the extensive documentation for finer control over the model fitting.